# Complex Arithmetic Expression using uniform random variables

Tags: statistics

Let $X, Y, Z \sim U(0,1)$. How would one solve for $W$?

\begin{equation}
 W = \frac{XY}{(X+Y+Z)^2}
\end{equation}

We can rewrite it as follows:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{W} = \frac{X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + 2XY + 2XZ + 2YZ}{XY}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{W} = \frac{X}{Y} + \frac{Y}{X} + \frac{Z^2}{XY} + 2 + 2\frac{Z}{Y} + 2 \frac{Z}{X}
\end{equation}

The ratio of two uniform RVs is

\begin{equation} 
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}I_{[0,1)}(x) + \frac{1}{2x^2}I_{[1,\infty)}(x)
\end{equation}

so we will use this in terms 1, 5, and 6 while we use the inverse distribution to $f$ in term 2.

This is as far as I have gotten. However, it looks like I may be off track.

Comment: What does it mean to "solve for $W$"? (Its distribution is wanted?) Please also define things like $X,Y,Z,U(0,1)$, at least roughly. Also, always show the own attempts to understand / solve the problem.

Comment: Sounds good. I will add my work. Yes. Solve for the distribution of W

Comment: It's not a sum of independent variables, am I wrong?